# Knockout bindings from JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js, data-binding

What am I doing wrong with my bindings?  I simply get `[object HTMLElement]` returned for each one.

Please note this is a pared-down version and I will be wanting to access the full range of the JSON values.

### Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0416f0s7/2/

### Code:

```
<div data-bind="text: intro"></div>

function ViewModel(stories) {
    var self = this;
    self.stories = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(stories, function(story) {
        return story.stories;
    }));
};

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    window.storyViewModel = new ViewModel(data.stories);
    ko.applyBindings(window.storyViewModel);
});
```

### JSON (filename `data.json`):

```
{
    "stories": [
        {
            "intro": "Hi",
            "outro": "Bye",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "title": "Title 1",
                    "image": "img/image1.jpg",
                    "paragraph": "Wordswordswords"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Title 2",
                    "image": "img/image2.jpg",
                    "paragraph": "More wordswordswords"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted is a bit *too* minimal. It doesn't reproduce the behavior you mention in the question (nor does the jsfiddle). If I try to fix the errors / missing bits in the code provide things [work just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j4cx9jnx/). Please update the question to contain a full but [mcve].

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle to meke it rork (https://jsfiddle.net/0416f0s7/4/). Your data item is wrapped in two arrays, so you can not bind to "intro" property - wrap in 2 foreach bindings, or get the property via "dots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your html change to**

```
`<div data-bind="foreach:stories">
        <div data-bind="text: intro"></div>
    </div>
```

**your code change to**

```
  function test(stories) {
        var self = this;
        self.stories = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(stories, function (story) {
            return story;
        }));

    }
```